# Problems with dotLess Stopping characters and hacks list?

Tags: dotless

Have any one run into trouble when running dotLess and having hacks on your CSS files? Been working on a project... just installed dotLess after one year of development to ease a little bit the job of creating new CSS files for some new functionality of the web site, and recently our old CSS is not working correctly.

---

Viewing the resulting CSS files we realized that the dotLess compiler stopeed at some hacks like this one:

```
html>/**/body #itemTable .informationView fieldset textarea { min-height: 1.3em; height: 1.3em; }
```

So we were wondering if there is any list of stopping words or hacks for dotLess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is that especially CSS hacks really wreck the parser.

We do have a workaround, but it's far from elegant at the moment: the insert statement.
It works the same way as the import statement, but it does not process the imported file, so it's ideal whenever you have code that can't be run through the parser (like copyright notices in comments or css hacks like yours) to just put them in a file somewhere and import them to your .less file.

I know, this is not perfect, we are currently working on a complete parser rewrite to improve the situation.

greetings Daniel